# How to serialize JSON key containing dots (like e.g. IP address) with SuperObject?

Tags: json, delphi, parsing, ip-address, superobject

I'm trying to save JSON where IP is a key. Expected JSON result is:

```json
{"SnmpManagers":[{"10.112.25.235":162}]}
```

The Delphi SuperObject code:

```
const
  IpAddr = '10.112.25.235';
  Port = 162;
var
  tmp: TSuperObject;
begin
  tmp := TSuperObject.Create;
  tmp.I[IpAddr] := Port;
  Json.A['SnmpManagers'].Add(tmp);
end;
```

SuperObject parses dots as path delimiters of a JSON object:

```json
{"SnmpManagers":[{"10":{"112":{"25":{"235":162}}}}]}
```

**How to save IP as a JSON key correctly with SuperObject ?**

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to create JSON object from string

```
Json.A['SnmpManagers'].Add(SO(Format('{"%s":%d}', [IpAddr, Port])));
```

Another way to add (do not use with .O[] because AsObject gives nil for non existing keys):

```
// for a simple key-value object
Json.AsObject.S['1.2.3'] := 'a'; // gives us {{"1.2.3":"a"}}
Json.AsObject.S['4.5'] := 'b'; // gives us {{"1.2.3":"a"}, {"4.5":"b"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
var    
  tmp: ISuperObject;
begin
  tmp := SO([IpAddr, port]);
  Json.A['SnmpManagers'].Add(tmp);
```