# How to access SuperObject object if key contains dots (e.g. Ip address)?

Tags: json, serialization, pascal, superobject

The code fails to access JSON object if it's key contain dots.

JSON:

```
"TableTraps": {    
  "1.3.6.1.4.1.100.108.0.3": {
    "Vars": [ 
      "alarmDescription", 
      "alarmPositionUnit", 
      "alarmChannel"
    ]
  },
  "1.3.6.1.4.1.100.108.0.4": {
    "Vars": [ 
      "alarmDescription", 
      "alarmPositionUnit", 
      "alarmChannel"
    ]
  },
}
```

Pascal SuperObject code:

```
TableTraps := LoadFromFile();
TrapOID := '1.3.6.1.4.1.100.108.0.3';
trapInfo := TableTraps.O[TrapOID];
```

Results in `trapInfo == nil` but I expect SuperObject instance.
I've tried to wrap the json key:

```
TrapOID := '"' + '1.3.6.1.4.1.100.108.0.3' + '"';
```

or

```
TrapOID := '''' + '1.3.6.1.4.1.100.108.0.3' + '''';
```

It doesn't help.

**How should I call SuperObject to access the object instance if the json key contains dots?**

Related question [How to serialize JSON key containing dots (like e.g. IP address) with SuperObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652878/how-to-serialize-json-key-containing-dots-like-e-g-ip-address-with-superobjec)

Answer (score 1):

Related question helped me to find the solution.
The `suprobject.O` called directly on the parsed object parses dots as JSONPath. So instead of accessing `"1.3.6.1.4.1.100.108.0.3: {}"` it tries to access this JSON:

```
"1": { "3": { "6": { "1": { "4": { "1": { "100": { "0": { "3": value
```

Here the workaround:

```
TableTraps := LoadFromFile();
TrapOID := '1.3.6.1.4.1.100.108.0.3';
trapInfo := TableTraps.AsObject.O[TrapOID]; // NOTE: AsObject is required!
```